# Forbidden 403 http request using deployment module

Tags: 7, deployment

When I use the deployment module on my local websites it works perfectly, I make a devlopment plan, add one or more endpoints, I select some nodes and then I deploy the plan and run Cron.
This way nodes that I selected are copied to my other sites in the multisite set-up.

When I use the exact some set-up for my live websites I get this error when executing the Cron:
Link to image: http://imageshack.com/a/img401/5973/bwju.png

This has to be something with the permissions when I look it up on the net but I cannot find a solution.
Link to module: https://drupal.org/project/deploy

Is there anyone that has tested this module and had the same issue and fixed it?
Or is there someone that can tell me what to fix to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nobody? Deployment module is really handy why does nobody use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my own question:

Add this to your .htaccess file (I have put it at the top):

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
# Paste the code under this sentence
<Limit PUT>
    allow from all
</Limit>
```